# A side note to the proof that $e$ is irrational

Tags: analysis

In my textbook (Elementary Analysis) there is a proof by contradiction that $e$ is irrational. Assume $e = \frac {a} {b}$ where $a,b \in \Bbb N$ then both $(b+1)!*e$ and (the part I don't understand)$$(b+1)!*\sum_{k=0}^{b+1} \frac{1} {k!}$$ are both integers. edit: Why is this summation an integer multiplied by b+1!?

Comment: Because every $k!$ divide $(b+1)!$.  So every term $\frac{(b+1)!}{k!}$  is an integer.

Comment: Note that we do not need to show that the summation is an integer. Indeed for $b\gt 0$ it isn't. What we need to show is that the summation *when multiplied by* $(b+1)!$, gives an integer.

Comment: @AndréNicolas noted

Answer (score 2):

Note that what you have is

$$(b+1)! \left( \frac{1}{0!} + \frac{1}{1!}+\cdots +\frac{1}{(b+1)!}\right).$$

The denominators are killing off the lowest $k$ terms in $(b+1)!$, leaving numerators of the form $(b+1)b\cdots(b-k-1)$.

Comment: Thanks for the correction, Gary! Silly me.